# Using JSDOM with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jsdom

I have an Angular 6 project and I want to parse html as browser do (with scripts etc.) so i decided to use JSDOM.
The thing is that I get a lot of errors when running `ng serve`.
Probably I have not installed some packages but I have already tried a lot of combinations and nothing worked.

This is my "invoke" of jsdom:

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);
```

Here is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.5",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "firebase": "^5.0.4",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.5",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jsdom": "11.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^10.3.4",
    "codelyzer": "^4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^11.11.0",
    "karma": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "ts-node": "^6.1.1",
    "tslint": "^5.10.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
```

and here are errors:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js
186:21-40 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/parse5/lib/index.js
55:23-49 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\sax\lib'

ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living'
ERROR in ./node_modules/aws4/aws4.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\aws4'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ecc-jsbn/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\ecc-jsbn'
ERROR in ./node_modules/oauth-sign/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\oauth-sign'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/helpers.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/hawk.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/oauth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/node_modules/aws-sign2/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\request\node_modules\aws-sign2'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/lib/verify.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\request\node_modules\http-signature\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/lib/signer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\request\node_modules\http-signature\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/private-key.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/identity.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/fingerprint.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/signature.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/dhe.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/key.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/certificate.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/openssh-cert.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\sshpk\lib\formats'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/pem.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\sshpk\lib\formats'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/ssh-private.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\sshpk\lib\formats'
ERROR in ./node_modules/cssstyle/lib/CSSStyleDeclaration.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\cssstyle\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living'
ERROR in ./node_modules/pn/fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\pn'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\forever-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\request'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/lib/signer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\request\node_modules\http-signature\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\forever-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\request'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\forever-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/file-api/Blob-impl.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\file-api'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/navigator/NavigatorConcurrentHardware-impl.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\navigator'
ERROR in ./node_modules/cssstyle/lib/CSSStyleDeclaration.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\cssstyle\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\mime-types'
ERROR in ./node_modules/combined-stream/lib/combined_stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\combined-stream\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/delayed-stream/lib/delayed_stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\delayed-stream\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/streams.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/extend-node.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/isstream/isstream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\isstream'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsprim/node_modules/assert-plus/assert.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\jsprim\node_modules\assert-plus'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\request'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/node_modules/assert-plus/assert.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\request\node_modules\assert-plus'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/ed-compat.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/node_modules/assert-plus/assert.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\sshpk\node_modules\assert-plus'
ERROR in ./node_modules/verror/node_modules/assert-plus/assert.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\verror\node_modules\assert-plus'
ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\forever-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'E:\moj-git\MovieApp\node_modules\request'
```

Answer (score 6):

The errors you are seeing is because `ng` is calling upon Webpack to pack JSDOM. Towards the end of [this issue](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/245) report you'll see that JSDOM can trivially be turned into a bundle that will run in the browser with `browserify` because `browserify` automatically provides replacements for the Node modules that JSDOM calls upon (like the `fs` module). Webpack does not provide such substitutions automatically. So you'd have to customize your application build to configure the Webpack run to provide such substitutions. Or use `browserify` as an independent step. I've written a few Angular applications but always rolled my own build process instead of using `ng` so I don't know how you'd work this out with `ng`.

---

This being said, I'm not seeing *why* you are using JSDOM at all.

> I have an Angular 6 project and I want to parse html as browser do (with scripts etc.)

Angular typically runs in the browser. There are things like Angular Universal and doing server-side rendering but there's nothing in your dependencies I see that indicates that's what you're trying to do. So, absent a clear declaration otherwise, the assumption is that you are using Angular in the way people normally do, as a browser application. In this case, then there's no point to using JSDOM. If you only want to *parse*, you can use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) instance. If you also want to execute the scripts that may be in the page, then you can create an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) that points to the source you want to execute, and turn on the `sandbox` flag on it and make use of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). JSDOM won't be faster, or safer than using `iframe`. The setting to tell JSDOM to run the scripts is `{ runScripts: "dangerously" }`, the reason being that, as stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#executing-scripts):

> The jsdom sandbox is not foolproof, and code running inside the DOM's `<script>`s can, if it tries hard enough, get access to the Node.js environment, and thus to your machine.

Don't get me wrong, I like JSDOM. I contributed code to it several occasions but I'm not seeing a reason for you to use it.

Comment: Thanks for this extensive explanation. So basicly instead of using JSDOM I can also use iframe and it should work? I need to try it.